# Do you have a development IDE hotkey set in AutoHotkey?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, scripting, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I've recently rejoined the [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) band wagon, and I've been setting up a master script for myself. Generally, I have a few global hotkeys, for doing things like popping open the calculator, and frequently used solutions. I even have a hotkey to restart certain local windows services, I've also got several contextual hotkeys that are only available when certain programs are active, but I don't have anything so far for my common IDE's. I generally develop in VS2008/2010 these days and they have a pretty robust [shortcut](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&displaylang=en) and code [snippet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx) system. Still, I can't help but wonder if anyone out there has come up with a useful set of hotkeys/hotstrings in AutoHotKey for their favorite development environments? I haven't seen much out there, but I'm always interested in ways to cut back my mundane tasks with automation.

Does anyone have any AutoHotkey scripts they use primarily for development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to now, with Windows Seven and pinning stuff to the taskbar, I can just press Win+7.  Good stuff.